# How to speedup product search queries

Tags: mysql, sorting, database-design, e-commerce

In my system I have 1 000 000 records in table products(id, price, name) , and assortment groups that have ~12 000 product each - table groups(group_id, product_id).

I would like to get products in group sorted by price/name/id/whatever. Join itself takes 300 ms, and then sorting (filesort) next 200, so I have lost 500 ms seconds just for sorting stuff, not speaking about joining other 30 tables to fetch business data.

I wonder how big other companies deal with it, for instance I can display 12 000 pages on amazon sorted by price. My competition has website that can display 1158 pages in less than 150 ms each (first hit is also 150 ms). It does not matter if catalog has 30 products, or 300 000.

What techniques and technologies should I use to achieve such speeds?

I already have all possible indexes, and playing with buffer sizes does not help.
Example query:

```
SELECT products.id
    FROM products
    JOIN  groups ON products.id = groups.product_id
    WHERE groups.group_id = '123'
    ORDER BY products.price DESC
    limit 10000, 100;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<rant>`It is a poor UI to have thousands of pages to flip through.  It is better to require the user to do some filtering before descending into a *small* number of 'pages'.`</rant>`  Back to your question...

If `group_id` and `price` were in the *same* table, the simple answer would be to add a composite `INDEX(group_id, price)`.  With that, the optimizer could filter on `group_id` *and* scan by `price` *and* get into the `LIMIT`.

Without that, the best that can be done is find all the rows with `group_id = 123`, find all their prices, sort the temp table, and only then look at `LIMIT`.  Note "all".

But...  `OFFSET`, itself, is a killer in *either* case.  The execution must step over 10000 rows before ariving at the 10 you want.  This problem I have a solution for.  Remember [*where you left off*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/).  (But, I repeat, this cannot be done with the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` split across two tables.)